# Using a dynamic range in a Index Match formula to return the max value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have got the following formula to return the maximum value/its area from my data:
=INDEX($1:$1,0,MATCH(MAX(2:2),2:2,0))

```
  |Col A  | Col B  | Col C  | ETC.
1 |       | Area 1 | Area 2 |
2 |Topic1 | 50.57  | 60.36  |
3 |Topic2 | 467.8  | 636.8  |
ETC.
```

In this case the formula would return 60.36 / Area 2 depending on the row used in the Index function.

However, there is no guarantee that all of the topics will be present so I want to use a dynamic row reference rather than fixing it at e.g. 2:2 - i.e. instead of simply 2:2 it would look for Topic1, find the maximum value in that row and return either the area or the value (I'll need both).

I've tried using something like
 =INDEX($1:$1,0,MATCH(MAX(MATCH("Topic1",A:A):MATCH("Topic1",A:A)),(MATCH("Topic1",A:A):MATCH("Topic1",A:A)),0)) 
without success.

I strongly suspect I'm missing something obvious but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sort of answered my own question. In case it helps anyone else I reorganized my data in a better format (each row: Topic1|Area1|Value) and used =MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,F1) to return the value and =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,A1),C:C,0)) to return the area name.

EDIT2: Can confirm that XOR LX solution also works - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=INDEX($1:$1,0,MATCH(MAX(INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH("Topic1",A:A,0),0)),INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH("Topic1",A:A,0),0),0))`

The use of zero as the `column_num` parameter within the part:

`INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH("Topic1",A:A,0),0)`

forces that function to return a reference to the entire row. That is, in this case, the above resolves to:

`INDEX($1:$1048576,2,0)`

which is here equivalent to:

`$2:$2`

See [here](https://excelxor.com/2014/08/18/index-returning-entire-rowscolumns/) for details of this property of `INDEX`.

You can also refer to the whole worksheet using:

`$A:$XFD`

in place of:

`$1:$1048576`

though Excel will in any case convert it to the latter once the formula is committed.

Regards